# Problem of disconnect clients on Socket.io

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, socket.io, next.js

Hi I am going to implement a project list with `socket.io` where any clients can update it.

For example, let's assume it's in such a format.

```
list 1
list 2
...
list 10k
```

A client can add a list say `list 2.1`, it will be stored to database and broadcast to other clients, and for efficiency we only broadcast `list 2.1`. The JavaScript program for all clients will insert it to the right position once receiving it, so now the list for all participants become:

```
list 1
list 2
list 2.1 
...
list 10k
```

Say now, client A and client B are tentatively disconnected from internet. And `list 2.2` and `list 2.3` are sent by other clients, and missed by client A and client B. After that client A and client B are then brought back, and received a new `list 2.4`. Their list become

```
list 1
list 2
list 2.1 
list 2.4
...
list 10k
```

which is incorrect (missing `list 2.2` and `list 2.3`). How do we handle such as issue in the frontend or backend code (I am using next.js and node.js)? (One possible solution of course is by retrieving data again from database, but how do we know whether the clients missed any listing?)

Comment: I think there's a lot of solutions, and the best one depends on the details we don't have here. One solution would be to just make a "registry" telling receiver what items they are expected to have, which they can then download if something is missing.

Comment: @vfioox "registry" should this be sent along in socket.io, and would that be a lot of information?

Comment: List/keyval of 10K elements? It's not terrible. But if you want to make absolutely sure everyone has the same set that might be necessary. At least I don't see another solution, besides optimizing. You could hash everyone's set and compare it against your _registry_ and if the set doesn't match, they could download the whole set(to avoid downloading it every time)

Comment: Technically they could send what they have, and the server can send back what they don't have. But that's potentially slower since servers usually have a synchronized connection, while clients upload speed tends to be much slower than their download speed. Plus, doing it that way creates more operations you don't need.

Comment: Still, we are most likely talking a lot less than 1MB so those are details.